# Create Dictionary from Array in Swift 5

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary from array with custom type for first index of the array.

Sample array : ["ABC","ZYZ","123"]

Required result : [{"name" : "ABC", "type:"A"},{"name" : "ZYZ", "type:"B"},{"name" : "123", "type:"B"}]

Note type A for first index.

My code

```
for url in urlArray {
        urlDict["name"] = url
    }
```

Comment: What's the logic here? Why is the first dictionary with `type:A` but the others with `type:B`?

Comment: First index of the array needs to sent to sever separately.

Comment: So it's _always_ the first index? It doesn't matter what the contents of the array are, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `map`, and then individually change the type of the first dictionary:

```
var dicts = urlArray.map { ["name": $0, "type": "B"] }
dicts[0]["type"] = "A"
```

---

Seeing how all your dictionary keys are all the same, and that you are sending this to a server, a `Codable` struct might be a better choice.

```
struct NameThisProperly : Codable {
    var name: String
    var type: String
}

var result = urlArray.map { NameThisProperly(name: $0, type: "B") }
result[0].type = "A"
do {
    let data = try JSONDecoder().encode(result)
    // you can now send this data to server
} catch let error {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can use a high order function such as `map` or `reduce`

Here is an example using `reduce`

```
var array = ["ABC","ZYZ","123"]

var result = array.reduce([[String: String]](), { (previous, current) -> [[String: String]] in
    let type = previous.count == 0 ? "A" : "B"
    let dictForCurrent = [
        "name": current,
        "type": type
    ]
    return previous + [dictForCurrent]
})

print(result)
```

The result:

> [["type": "A", "name": "ABC"], ["type": "B", "name": "ZYZ"], ["name":
>   "123", "type": "B"]]

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce` to convert array to dictionary:

```
let resultDict: [String: String]
      = array.reduce(into: [:]) { dict, url in
        dict["name"] = url
      }
```

The result will look like:

```
[
  "name": URL1,
  "name": URL2
]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`map(_:)`** to convert each element of the `array` to `dictionary` like so,

```
let arr = ["ABC","ZYZ","123"]
let result = arr.map { (element) -> [String:String] in
    var dict = [String:String]()
    dict["name"] = element
    if let char = element.first {
        dict["type"] = String(char)
    }
    return dict
}

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are concern about the index, my approach will be using `enumerated()` which gives out the index

```swift
   let array = ["ABC","ZYZ","123"]
   var results: [[String: String]] = []
   for (i, content) in array.enumerated() {
      let type: String = i == 0 ? "A" : "B"
      results.append(["name": content, "type": type])
    }
    print(result)

// [["type": "A", "name": "ABC"], ["name": "ZYZ", "type": "B"], ["type": "B", "name": "123"]]
```